# Spring ws logging issue with SLF4j

Tags: web-services, logging, soap, spring-ws

Hi I am using spring ws + slf4j for logging. While logging soap request & response using below propertiesin application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.sent=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
```

Instead of logging request & response it prints the following object,

```
13:13:06.155 [main] DEBUG o.s.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent - Sent request  [SaajSoapMessage {http://ws.sample.customer.com/}getCustomerDetails]
13:13:06.411 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.client.MessageTracing.received - Received   response [SaajSoapMessage  {http://ws.sample.customer.com/}getCustomerDetailsResponse] for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://ws.sample.customer.com/}getCustomerDetails]
```

I am calling webservice using following way :

```
 return (JAXBElement) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(uri, request, webServiceMessage -> {
            SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) webServiceMessage;
            Marshaller marshaller = getMarshaller();
            marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, soapMessage.getSoapHeader().getResult());
        });
```

I don't know why it is not printing the request & response. Also I tried to intercept the request & response using "SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor" or "ClientInterceptor" but nothing get triggered but got the response object.

```
public class LogbackInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogbackInterceptor.class);

 public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
       logger.debug("Sent request by sample [" + messageContext.getRequest() + "]");
       return true;
 }

 public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
       logger.debug("Received response by sample [" + messageContext.getResponse() + "] for request [" +
                            messageContext.getRequest() + "]");
       return true;
 }

@Override
public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Exception ex) throws WebServiceClientException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

```
@Component
public class LoggingInterceptor  extends SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor{

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);

@Override
protected void logMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("Entered log message");
    logger.debug("LoggingInterceptor::logMessage");
    logger.debug(message);
/* Example, here you could be logging to DB or whatever you want */
}
}
```

It would be great if someone helped me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution hope it should help others,

We should register "ClientInterceptor" in WebServiceTemplate otherwise spring won't trigger "ClientInterceptor".The below code works like a charm and now i am able to intercept request & response.

```
WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = getWebServiceTemplate();
ClientInterceptor[] interceptors = new ClientInterceptor[1];
interceptors[0] = new LogbackInterceptor();
webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
```

Comment: LogbackInterceptor is an interface. How is this code working ?